# How to get exact url passing as arv using sys

Tags: python

```
import sys
url = sys.argv[1]
print(url)

Command : python test.py https://s3.amazonaws.com/apm_prod_00f03632faded6cf0aafb3de4895e9eb/d_20230519_174025.heic%22\u0026X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\u0026X-Amz-Credential
```

When I run on terminal the exact url is not passing instead of ""\u0026"" its getting ""22u0026"" Is there any solution to get exact url

Comment: What kind of shell are you using? In which operating system?

Comment: Pycharm terminal.. Ubuntu linux

Comment: Not really a Python issue.  It depends on how your shell parses command lines and passes those parameters on to Python.

Comment: Wrap the argument in double-quotes

Comment: @DarkKnight i tried its not working

Comment: Backslashes are not allowed in a URL.  The Python code "\u0026" is the ampersand character (`&`).  Just use that instead.

Comment: Applying double-quotes works correctly in both bash and ksh. I have no idea what you're doing wrong. @TimRoberts makes a fair point. Why would you want (literally) \u0026 ?

Answer (score 0):

Try finding out what shell you're in using the command `echo $SHELL` or `echo $0`.

I recommend replacing the `\u0026` with the `&` character.

You can fix the issue by enclosing the URL within a pair of double quotes, as in `"https://example.com"`.